# Postfix/Dovecot - User unknown in table, setting it up with /etc/virtual/domain/passwd

Tags: postfix, email-server, dovecot

I'm trying for two days to replace Exim with Postfix.
I'm able to log into my mail account and send mail from localhost to another sever with telnet, but i cannot send anything to my postfix/dovecot server. I'm getting "User unknown in local recipient table".

I'm having all virtual accounts data in /etc/virtual/domain/passwd files. Is there any way to force Postfix/Dovecot to use and understand this file correctly?

Current main.cf file (replaced host and domains data):

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = vps.fripersvps.kylos.net.pl

myorigin = evilbananastudio.pl
mydestination = $myhostname, vps.fripersvps.kylos.net.pl, evilbananastudio.pl
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 193.107.90.163
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
relay_domains = evilbananastudio.pl

config_directory = /etc/postfix
message_size_limit = 4194304

virtual_transport = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
virtual_mailbox_domains = evilbananastudio.pl
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/fripers/imap
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

My postconf -Mf:

```
smtp       inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
pickup     unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup    unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr       unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite    unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer      unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace      unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush      unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp       unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
showq      unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error      unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry      unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard    unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp       unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil      unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache     unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
maildrop   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DRhu
    user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp       unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fqhu
    user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=F user=ftn
    argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fq.
    user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix - n       n       -       2       pipe flags=R
    user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop}
    ${user} ${extension}
mailman    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=FR
    user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py ${nexthop}
    ${user}
```

EDIT & UPDATE: I've updated files with some information from postfix readme and currently getting: 451 4.3.0 mateusz@evilbananastudio.pl: Temporary lookup failure

Comment: well, *have* you configured dovecot to use your user list? (you can use `dovecot -n` to get a serialized dump of your effective configuration changes)

Comment: Did you read Postfix's VIRTUAL_README http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html ? Which of suggested ways to configure did you go? In particular, where and how did you set up your local or virtual users in the Postfix configuration? I handn't found any traces of that in your paste. By the way, better show us a complete and untouched output of `postconf -Mf` instead of that paste.

Comment: dovecot -n gives me output of configuration file where I've got:
`passdb {
  args = username_format=%n /etc/virtual/%d/passwd
  driver = passwd-file
} ` So in my opinion it's configured fine.

Comment: Added `postconf -Mf` results in my question, I did not read Postfix VIRTUAL_README, I've based on general internet tutorials. I'm going to dig into README right now.

Comment: Looked at VIRTUAL_README and made some fixes based on "Non-Postfix mailbox store: separate domains, non-UNIX accounts", currently getting when trying to send mail via telnet on localhost (from mailbox to this same mailbox address) after RCPTO TO: 451 4.3.0 <mateusz@evilbananastudio.pl>: Temporary lookup failure. Still no idea what's going on :(